# Is there .NET component which can convert XLS to password protected PDFs?

Tags: .net, excel, pdf, components

Is there .NET component which can convert XLS to password protected PDFs?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[CutePDF Professional](http://cutepdf.com/Products/CutePDF/Pro.asp) supports password protected files.  It will output any printable document to PDF, including XLS files.  A redistributable version is available.  Excel is required.

Comment: There are a couple of things I don't like: 
CutePDF Writer will have to be installed on all computers along with PS2PDF converter (well, maybe we can install it only on server and use as a network printer).  
As for CutePDF Form SDK, which is a stand-alone library as I understood, it starts at $250.

Comment: There are other ways, but they are more expensive, and they still require a software component.  The redistributable version can be integrated into your application, if that is what you are after.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I haven't found the redistributable version. Can you please help with the exact link?